# Добавить/показать комментарий к посту в блоге на PHP/MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте! Учу php, делаю блог, пытаюсь связать комментарии к постам. То есть, сделать так, чтоб каждый комментарий был связан со своим постом. Проблема в том, что не могу сообразить как правильно query реализовать, чтоб показывать именно связанные комменты с постами, а не все сразу. Вот query, до которого я мучительно додумался, но он все-же не выводит ничего, явно составлен неверно:

```
SELECT `commentID`, `name`, `content`, `post_id`, `date` 
FROM `blog_comments` 
WHERE `post_id` = `commentID`'
```

Я так понял, мне надо связать `postID` с `post_id` в таблице `blog_comments`. До всего этого додумался, но как правильно в коде реализовать не могу, знание синтаксиса еще слишком слабое :)
Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь и направление, спасибо большое!
Также мои таблицы:

**blog_posts:**

```
postID (Primary)    int(11)       No                
postTitle           varchar(255)  Yes   NULL            
postDesc            text          Yes   NULL            
postCont            text          Yes   NULL            
postDate            datetime      Yes   NULL
```

**blog_comments**

```
commentID (Primary) int(11)        No               
name                varchar(55)    No               
content             varchar(255)   No               
post_id             int(11)        No   blog_posts -> postID        
date                timestamp      No   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В целом вы на правильном пути, критерий выборки у вас действительно должен сравнивать `blog_comments.post_id` и `blog_posts.postId`, но в условии вы почему то сравниваете другие поля.

Как бы то ни было. На некоторой странице вы показываете пост и его комменты. Для показа нужного поста, у вас видимо в параметрах URL есть его `Id`, который в php-коде вы получаете, например, в виде `$_GET['post_id']`.
Далее вам необходимо выбрать всю информацию о посте. Для этого вы должны написать запрос вида:

```
SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE postId = :id
```

*Возьмите за правило хорошего тона сразу никогда не подставлять переданные параметры напрямую в запрос, по крайней мере без предварительной проверки. Если вы напишите код вида `$sql = "select * from blog_posts where postId = ${_GET['id]}"`, то при передаче в качестве id строки  вида `1; delete from posts;` приведет к удалению ваших данных. Если вы хотите подставить значение напрямую в запрос, то по крайней мере проверьте его с помощью [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.is-numeric.php) или [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.intval.php). Не забудьте почитать про [SQL-инъекции](http://php.net/manual/ru/security.database.sql-injection.php)*

[Для работы с БД](http://php.net/manual/ru/refs.database.php) используйте современные расширения, например, [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php). Читая старые книги, вы часто можете встретить использование функций `mysql_*` (не путать с `mysqli_`). Они уже устарели.

Учитывая вышеизложенное, ваш код выборки должен выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM blog_posts  WHERE postID = :id');
$sth->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Теперь вы хотите загрузить связанные комментарии. Используйте для этого второй запрос. В целом связывать таблицы здесь и не надо:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM blog_comments WHERE post_id = :id ORDER BY date DESC";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();

$result['comments'] = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Теперь в переменной `$result` будут содержаться данные поста и комментарии. Осталось показать их пользователю. Многие мешают вместе в одном файле логику работы (php-код) и отображение данных (представление, html). Это плохой подход, так что лучше сразу глянуть в сторону движков шаблонов как [smarty](/questions/tagged/smarty), [twig](/questions/tagged/twig) и т.п.
Так то теперь останется оформить html-код и вывести данные.

И на заметку по именование полей ваших таблиц. Первичный ключ обычно именуют просто `id`. Нет никакого смысла называть их `postId` или `commentId`, так чаще именуют поля внешних ключей (`postId` или `post_id`). То есть первичный ключ просто `id`, а внешний ключ обычно содержит имя внешней таблицы и суффикс `id`, `_id`, `_ID` и т.п.

*Ну а на последок, если вы дочитали до этих строк, то прежде чем начинать изучать php, уделите немного времени изучению баз данных. Прочитайте какую-нибудь небольшую книжку, которая вам даст понимание основ их использования. И вам будет легче продолжить изучение.*

Comment: Спасибо большое за столь хороший и развернутый ответ! Учусь по новой книге, в которой меня научили использовать mysqli, про устаревший mysql в курсе. Smarty тоже учу, а также разделение кода по принципу MVC. Раздражает все это ужасно, но стараюсь прививать хорошие практики, и по поводу sql запросов и безопасности, я тоже об этом беспокоюсь. С pdo еще толком не разобрался, моментами темный лес, mysqli легче. Я попробую Ваши предложения на практике и еще отпишусь, спасибо большое!